# Why is `qmake -v` version not changing after installing later version?

Tags: macos, qt

I'm updating my version of `Qt` for development purposes on my mac.

So I downloaded and installed the opens-source `.dmg` from the `Qt` website (https://www.qt.io/).

During installation, I specifically checked the box to install version `5.0.2`.

But afterwards, when running `qmake -v`, it still says the version is `4.8.7`.

```
Make version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.8.7 in /Users/my_dir/anaconda/lib
```

(Note: it also points to `/lib` directory in `/anaconda`, even though I'm setting this up for Rails purposes. Not sure if this has any impact.)

Can anyone advise how I can change the version that is being pointed to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is what worked for me, incase anyone else has this issue.

1. Check which version of `qmake` is being used. `which qmake`.
2. Remove `anaconda` from mac $PATH.
3. Force homebrew to symlink binaries. `brew link --force qt55`.
4. Re-check which version of `qmake` is being used. `which qmake`.

When you check the version of `qmake` the second time, it should point to the new version of `qmake` that you have installed.

Note: You will have to redo this for every terminal session where you want to use the newer version of `qmake`.